# how to get a specific user's message count from a whole discord server without the bot always being online

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there any method where I could create a very simple bot that, whenever I need , is run and connects to a server, where it can read and count all messages for specific users over a specific time period?

For example, I would run the bot, use a simple command in any channel that started it to read through every user's message over a week, which it then simply outputs and I can turn it off. No need to store any of thee information for later.

Any ideas for what could be the solution?

Comment: In addition to the answer by stijndcl I'll point out this smells like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why are you trying to do this? What is the real problem?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by the Discord API - bots don't have access to searching in the same manner that users do.

The only way to get this is traversing the entire message history ([docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=history#discord.abc.Messageable.history)) and checking every single message (albeit within a timeframe), but this will take **ages** even for small servers because of the ratelimits that apply.

There is no way to implement this feature in a realistic setting while keeping it functional when the bot is down.